# Executar Splashscreen no android apenas a primeira vez, que o usuario abre o aplicativo?

Tags: android

apos a instalaçao,gostaria de saber como fazer para executar a splashscreen apenas na primeira vez que o usuario abre  app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode salvar uma uma variável no SharedPreferences a primeira vez que o Splash for executado, depois verificar essa variável para mostrar ou não o Splash nas próximas vezes.